# ajax call not working after calling load() function

Tags: jquery, ajax

m trying to refresh the div after making an ajax call but only the first ajax call working. after loading the div again ajax call is dead.

```
$('.sequence_no').on("change", function () {
        var selector = $(this).closest("tr");
        var sequence_no = $(this).val();
        var s_no = selector.find('.sno').val();
        var chapter_id = selector.find('.chapter_id').val();
        var lesson_id = selector.find('input[class*=lesson_id]').val();
        console.log(chapter_id);

        $.ajax({
            url: "../chapter-page/sequence.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { chapter_id: chapter_id, lesson_id: lesson_id, sequence_no: sequence_no },
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {

                console.log(data);

                $("#table2").load(window.location.href + " #table2");



            }

        })
    })
```

everything is working if I don't put the .load() function in the success

I am new to jquery so a descriptive answer will help me to learn.

can anybody help??

Comment: Is `.sequence_no` inside `#table2`? If so you have to rebind the `onchange` event after the `.load()`

Comment: try using async: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: thanks for taking time @David yes it is inside table2 but i don't understand the rebind thing

Comment: Hi, just change `$('.sequence_no').on("change", function () {` to `$(document).on("change",".sequence_no",function(){ //all code here })` see if that works .

Answer (score 0):

`$.on` binds an event to a function for the elements it is passed to (in this case `.sequence_no`). When you call `.load()` on `#table2`, you are for all intents and purposes removing the contents of `#table2` and replacing it with newly loaded HTML.

Since you noted that `.sequence_no` is inside `#table2`, it is removed when `.load` is called and then, presumably it is replaced with the newly loaded HTML, but the binding of `onchange` happened before the new element was loaded, so it needs to be bound again.

TL;DR you need to call the entire `$.on` function again after the `$.load` call completes.

Comment: well i researched it and i already know that newly loaded html is the problem, but you said "you need to call the entire $.on function again after the $.load call completes." do you mean i have to put the same code into the success?? if yes then how many times. and also some sample code is very much appreciated. i can understand that i have to call .on function but where and when.

Comment: Put the $.on inside a named function like `function bindChange()` for example, and then call `bindChange()` inside the success callback of $.load.